# using JPA how to read .properties file in persistence file

Tags: xml, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, persistence

How to read properties file in **persistence.xml**

I wanrt to read db user and password from a properties file for persistence.xml

Comment: You don't. A `persistence.xml` allows you to specify the properties, so specify them there. There is no JPA option to put properties in a separate file. You could of course create an EMF using override properties and read the override properties in YOURSELF (second argument to `createEntityManagerFactory(...)`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically this kind of stuff is done by using build tools that manipulate setting files - like persistence.xml - by replacing needed parameters in that file before packaging.

For example i use Maven and filtering in my java (mainly j2ee) projects to replace placeholders for persistence unit name or other needed project specific settings. Just because i like to keep all the configuration stuff in profiles and in one file.

However this is an another topic and cannot be explained here briefly.

Comment: @phiro Could you please explain it briefly.